# Estimate the Beta Coefficients, and then find an algorithm

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, nonlinear, nls

Referring to the photo, I need to report my beta coefficients as functions of observed Xi and Yi. I tried to reduce by taking the log of both sides but It seems I can't reduce this model because it is non linear in the parameters. Any help?

[image]

Comment: You can reparameterize the model to make it linear in two of the parameters, but it is inherently nonlinear in $\beta_1.$  So, re-read the original question carefully (it takes great care because of the bad grammar) and focus on what it's asking you to do.